# Producer/consumer table in mysql - missing rows

Tags: mysql, database

I've got a mysql table being used as a message queue:

```
id | message_text
```

It's an InnoDB table, and the id field is an auto increment integer field.

The producer app has multiple threads which perform inserts like:

```
insert into my_table(message_text) values('the text');
```

The consumer app runs every five seconds. It selects 50 records, then deletes each by the row id:

```
rows = select * from my_table limit 50;
for (row : rows) {
    delete from my_table where id = row.id;
}
```

It seems like the consumer app does not see all the rows. There is only one producer app instance running, and it does the selects in a single thread. The producer app prints to console all the messages it's inserting, and the consumer app also prints each row it handles, but it's missing rows.

I thought since I'm explicitly deleting by row ID I wouldn't run into problems, but it seems like I'm definitely dropping rows somewhere.

Thanks

Comment: How fast the producer creates messages? Couldn't it be that the consumer simply can't catch up?

Comment: Not fast at all, like 1 a second.

Comment: Well if you’re deleting by ids of rows “already seen” only, then the consumer should see them on one of the next runs … unless maybe they are “never seen” because there are too many. Are you just selecting rows without any `ORDER BY` applied? That would make _what_ the consumer gets to see _when_ quite random … so I’d suggest to include ordering, and see what results you get with that.

Comment: Yeah that was my thinking, they should eventually get seen by the consumer. But I shut the producer down and let the consumer keep going. The consumer somehow is never seeing some of the rows. If this should work in theory, then I must have introduced a problem somewhere.

Comment: Without the order by they would come in order of the primary key I believe which is I guess even the expected behavior. However adding an order by certainly would not hurt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh this was just a dumb mistake on my part. My initial code test (in jdbc) had auto-commit off in one of the threads, and I was failing to explicitly commit. This resulted in me thinking some of the rows were getting dropped.

I can confirm this pattern works now as expected.